# C: glibc detected malloc(): memory corruption: ... segfault

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am trying to run a program I have in C.  I have a stack ADT I made as part of this program and when I try to make a new stack (which is only done once), I get `*** glibc detected *** ./lcs_prog: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000007e10c0 ***`

the function being called is newStack() defined as

```
StackP newStack(void)
{
    StackP temp;
    temp = (StackP)malloc(sizeof(StackT));
    temp->size = 0;
    return temp;
}
```

where StackP is defined in a header file as `typedef struct StackT *StackP;` and the stucture is

```
typedef struct StackT
{
    StackItem content[MAX_SIZE];
    int size;
}StackT;
```

I use malloc in three other places (two char* and one int*) in the program which successfully complete by the time this error occurs.  the program immediately segfaults after a call to newStack().

**Output from valgrind:**

```
[user@cs-ssh1 student-p5]$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./lcs_prog
==13885== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13885== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13885== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13885== Command: ./lcs_prog
==13885==
==13885==
==13885== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x7fee17d60 --> 0x7ff0001f0
==13885==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=2000016 or greater
First string:  ABCBDAB
Second string: BDCABA
==13885== Invalid write of size 4
==13885==    at 0x400F54: lengthLCS (part1.c:61)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b408 is 0 bytes after a block of size 168 alloc'd
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400F2B: lengthLCS (part1.c:58)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==
==13885== Invalid read of size 4
==13885==    at 0x401071: lengthLCS (part1.c:70)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b408 is 0 bytes after a block of size 168 alloc'd
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400F2B: lengthLCS (part1.c:58)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==
==13885== Invalid write of size 4
==13885==    at 0x4010B1: lengthLCS (part1.c:71)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b40c is 4 bytes after a block of size 168 alloc'd
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400F2B: lengthLCS (part1.c:58)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==
==13885== Invalid write of size 4
==13885==    at 0x40102A: lengthLCS (part1.c:68)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b418 is 16 bytes after a block of size 168 alloc'd
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400F2B: lengthLCS (part1.c:58)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==
==13885== Invalid read of size 4
==13885==    at 0x401025: lengthLCS (part1.c:68)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b408 is 0 bytes after a block of size 168 alloc'd
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400F2B: lengthLCS (part1.c:58)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==
==13885== Invalid read of size 4
==13885==    at 0x40104F: lengthLCS (part1.c:70)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b410 is 8 bytes after a block of size 168 alloc'd
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400F2B: lengthLCS (part1.c:58)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==
==13885== Invalid read of size 4
==13885==    at 0x4010AF: lengthLCS (part1.c:71)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b410 is 8 bytes after a block of size 168 alloc'd
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400F2B: lengthLCS (part1.c:58)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==
==13885== Invalid read of size 4
==13885==    at 0x40112E: lengthLCS (part1.c:77)
==13885==    by 0x40121B: printResults (part1.c:100)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)
==13885==  Address 0x4c1b43c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13885==
Length of LCS: 4
--13885-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--13885-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x304C1B42A;  sp: 0x402f08dd0

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal
==13885==    at 0x3803EC04: vgPlain_arena_malloc (m_mallocfree.c:291)
==13885==    by 0x38003C34: vgMemCheck_new_block (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:263)
==13885==    by 0x3800409A: vgMemCheck_malloc (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:301)
==13885==    by 0x3807A58A: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1665)
==13885==    by 0x380A5A19: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:103)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==13885==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==13885==    by 0x400B2D: newStack (stack.c:32)
==13885==    by 0x401153: stringLCS (part1.c:85)
==13885==    by 0x401236: printResults (part1.c:101)
==13885==    by 0x40139D: main (main.c:18)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

The lengthLCS malloc errors are likely from me accessing an integer array that was made using malloc (successfully).

Any help in this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**EDIT**

After reviewing my code, I found I had an off-by-one error in my lengthLCS function (not posted) I was going outside the bounds of a malloc'd array of integers.  Fixing this has fixed the problem.  Thank you for your time and comments.

Comment: you are maybe using free twice on the same pointer

Comment: Can you include lengthLCS method as well?  It looks like something in there is causing memory corruption.  That memory corruption can easily cause a problem sometime later in your program, depending on what was in the corrupted memory area.

Comment: `StackP` `StackT` looks like typedef disease. You want `StackT *ptr = (StackT *) malloc(sizeof *ptr);` (where the cast is included for C++ compatibility).

Comment: `StackT` and `StackP` can be defined in the same declaration. `typedef struct { whatever } StackT, *StackP;`. Less error prone.

Comment: Alexis, at this point in my project, I haven't been able to call free for anything yet.

Velox, You were right there.  My lengthLCS function had an off-by-one error.  I fixed it there. Thanks.

Kaz, I know it looks like typedef disease, but StackP is the only type in the stack.h file. The professor has requested it be this way.  You're way is a lot more elegant, but I have to do what is asked of me.  Thank you though.